# load node in drupal the php code is not working

Tags: php, drupal

I have created a node accessing the content using node_load method. 
The php code embedded in the node is printing as text rather than executing the php script.

```
<?php 
    $theme_path = $base_path.path_to_theme(); 
?>
<img src="<?php print $theme_path;?>/images/menu-line.png" width="113" height="1">
```

And accessing this node from the page.tpl.php using the node_load method.

```
<?php 
    $result  = node_load(array('title' => 'node menu'));
    print $result->body; 
?>
```

Comment: Do you have one of the WYSIWYG style editors installed? Perhaps something is HTML-encoding your PHP. Does your PHP text format have any of the special processing options turned on (like automatically clean HTML, restrict to certain tags, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your text format of that node is set to filtered or full HTML. It should be set to php.

Comment: It is set to PHP filter